# Subject-Verb agreement in sentences with "all I see," "all he hears," etc,

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

In sentences like "All he can think of is this moment," *all* is taking singular *is*. However, in sentences where there is more than one subject, does *all* still take singular *is*?

> 1. **All** he can hear **is** the wind, the sound of the rain, and the thunder.
> 2. **All** that's present at the end of the hall **is** the storage and another room.

Do both these sentences take "all...is"? Could this be explained with a grammatical rule? In these sentences, is *all* referring back to predicate nominatives?

Comment: Similar, I think: [“When all you hear is fear and lies”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74072)

Comment: Yes, "be" is used in its specifying sense here, and the complement specifies the value of the variable defined in the subject "all". Constructions like this are very similar in meaning to pseudo-clefts, cf. "All he can hear is the wind, the sound of the rain, and the thunder" ~ "What he can hear is the wind, the sound of the rain, and the thunder". Singular agreement is normal.

Comment: So, in pseudo-cleft sentences with "all," where there are more than one emphasized elements in the second part of the sentence, singular agreement is always preferable? As opposed to a sentence like this: 
All she saw in the sky were stars. But, All I can remember is her face, the smile of the child, and the warm sun of the summer. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["When all you hear is fear and lies"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74072/when-all-you-hear-is-fear-and-lies)

Comment: @skywardhope: Even when the elements are plural, you have a choice. [Edna St. Vincent Millay:](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/55993/renascence) *All I could see from where I stood // Was three long mountains and a wood*.

Comment: _All she saw were stars_ sounds like somebody asked her to look for meteors. But _was_ would also be OK with that meeting. You need a really good reason to use a plural in a cleft. Normally the subject is a construction instead of a noun anyway.