# All I can think about is vs all I can think about are

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, pronouns, verb-agreement

> All I can think about is the sun, oak tree, and large bird.

vs.

> All I can think about are the sun, oak tree, and large bird.

Comment: Technically, *is* has to agree with *all* (or the phrase headed by *all*), not the list that follows. There are arguments for both singular and plural agreement. Some examples: *all is well*; *all are present*. In your case, it could be either, depending on whether you're treating all you could think about as a compound whole or as separate elements.

Comment: They are separate elements on my mind.

Comment: Similar: [“When all you hear is fear and lies”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74072)

Comment: @sumelic 'Fear' isn't count their, which makes a significant difference.

Comment: This has been addressed before, but in two parts. [a] 'All the X' may take a singular ('All the money has gone') or plural ('All the men were there') verb-form. // [b] notional override is often used (and, I'd say, often preferable): 'Bacon and eggs is my favourite meal. I'm so hungry that all I can think about is bacon and eggs.' With a coordinated list considered largely as a whole, I'd use a singular verb-form. _But_, with a list of items considered as separate elements ('Bacon and eggs have both risen in price this year'), a plural ...

Comment: verb-form is required. In your case, I'd say you can justifiably choose how to emphasise. But if choosing _are_, I'd compartmentalise more clearly: 'are the sun, the oak tree, and the large bird.'

Comment: You need a really good reason, and a clear exposition, to use a plural _be_ in a cleft. The tense of the fulcrum of cleavage is normally irrelevant, since it's inserted by rule like _it_ and _there_.