# Is there a conceptual influence on plurality according to definable/indefinable number?

Tags: grammatical-number, predicative-complements

I found that my instinct was to say 'All I can see is the cat's whiskers' but my instinct was also to say 'All I can see are the cat's eyes'.

After some thought, either this is just a personal quirk of my own experience of the English language, or this is something that is idiomatic (perhaps only in my native British English or even more locally, my Scottish background) or . . . .

. . . .  it is a genuine conceptual effect of expressing a clearly definable number (a pair) as a plural and expressing an indefinable excess as a collective singular.

Does the indefinability of a number (greater than, say a pair or a trio) affect it's usage as a collective singular in situations where there is an ambiguity of grammatical expression ?

Comment: “ All I could see from where I stood
Was three long mountains and a wood;” —-Edna St. Vincent Millay

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["When all you hear is fear and lies"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74072/when-all-you-hear-is-fear-and-lies). Allowing for synesis here, the question is still not simple: does 'all' equate to 'the only thing' or 'the only things'? 'Rules' conflict hereabouts. It's easiest to avoid bunfights by rephrasing: "I can see nothing but the cat's whiskers".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, that nailed it. Thank you.