# "All that I see is lights" or "All that I see are lights"

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, creative-writing

I am in a heated debate over whether to use "is" or "are" in the following sentence:

"When I look into her eyes all I see **is/are** bright lights beaming energy through our path on eternity together."

Please advise.

Comment: There are already a couple of similar questions on the English language stack exchange.

Comment: please see: https://grammarhow.com/is-all-singular-or-plural/   
the 'all' in your sentence is 'lights' (plural)

Comment: Thanks for the resource, but these are not direct enough answers to my complex question, and the involved parties want a definitive answer if one exists.

Comment: I believe this thread _does_ answer your question, Big S: ["When all you hear is fear and lies"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74072/when-all-you-hear-is-fear-and-lies) Fowler's gives a definitive answer: ' ... all I see **_is_** bright lights'. (Cool Elf comes up with the killer example: 'All I want for Christmas is my two front teeth'.)

Comment: Thanks, Edwin. I would’ve liked a definitive (and upvoted) answer in this thread so I could share it with the debatees.

Answer (score 0):

**All I see are lights**

The object that you are looking at is plural. If you said "all I see is light" then you would use the singular "is."

You might get confused by the subject being singular, but let me put it this way. Let's say that you wanted to say "all I see is/are light" and you make the direct object singular. You would say "all I see *is* light". "Are" doesn't sound right in that case. To show that the subject doesn't matter, now make the sentence "all they see is/are light." The subject is plural, but you still would use is. The only thing that matters is if the direct object is plural or not.

(By the way, the direct object is what the verb is directly acting upon. For example with your sentence, ask the question "what do you see?" You see light. The direct object is light.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The verb needs to agree with the subject of the sentence.

Your subject is singular (I) so the correct verb is 'is'

The exception to this is when the subject is a collective noun -- such as a murder of crows. The murder is singular but refers to more than one crow so a sentence whose subject is a murder of crows would use 'are' and not 'is'

Comment: The main sentence is "All is/are lights". "I" is only the subject of the subordinate clause "(that) I see" and has nothing to do with the verb in question.

Comment: @Divizna, I think you've gotten that backwards.  'When I look into ...' is a subordinated clause. It starts with a conditional word and can't stand alone. The independent clause is 'All I see ... beaming energy.' And the subject of the independent clause is I.

Comment: It's possible for a compound sentence to have more than one subordinate clause. I insist that the part "(that) I see" is a subordinate clause and the verb paired with "I" in it is "see".

Comment: I'm reasonably confident "**I is...**" is not the correct answer.